# can .gz files be split in Kafka partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, gzip, kafka-consumer-api

We have a use case where one of the producer will produce .gz files as output, can we split into chunks in kafka partitions? if not what is the way around

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “ split into chunks in kafka partions” but if you put chunks into different partitions it will be hard to reconstruct the file because multiple consumers could consume data from different partitions. If you really want to put chuncs into Kafka put them into the same partition. Typically better solution is to store file in some temporary storage and send some id to kafka

Answer (score 0):

Kafka just stores bytes; you can store whatever you want.

But it is not intended to store *files*. One example - if you split the file over multiple partitions, then there is no guaranteed ordering in which your consumers will read it, and you would ideally only have one consumer reading all partitions to actually combine the file back together. Having multiple partitions but forced to use one consumer is a Kafka design anti-pattern.

If the goal is to have compressed data, you can set `compression.type=gzip` for regular events, but if you want to actually transfer files via Kafka topics, it is better to place the entire file on a shared filesystem (NFS, S3) then send a **file URI as a string** within the topic for consumers to then download.